# Render Linux VM applications on Windows Host Xserver

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, x-server, xforwarding

I have a Ubuntu VM on VirtualBox running in headless mode. Host is a Windows 10 machine. I want to be able to render Ubuntu's applications on Windows using XServer.

Currently, I tried this:

- Installed X410 XServer on Windows.
- ssh into Virtual Machine with a `-X` option so that X forwarding is enabled.
- If I run a graphical application from command line now, it complains that cannot connect XServer. My DISPLAY env variable is `localhost:10.0`.

Below is error I get on launching the graphical application:

```
connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X0: No such file or directory Unable to init  
server: Could not connect: Connection refused Failed to parse  
arguments: Cannot open display:
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter the IP of the host machine, not `localhost`. And also check what is the display number for your X server.
The command should be:

```
export DISPLAY=<host IP>:<host display>.0
```

Comment: I am using NAT networking so both have the same hostname. Do I need to setup port forwarding instead?
How can I find out display number for my X server? I think it is 0 but I am not sure.

Comment: You did the forward (by using `-X` in `ssh`

Comment: Oh yeah!! Sorry about that.
Can you please respond to other questions?